# Content loaded 2 times by javascript

Tags: javascript, load

I'm making a simple example with javascript. I'm adding elements to a html file dynamically by javascript for then, using this new created content to apply another javascript functions. Logically the content of the page is doing 2 times, once to load original html, twice to load the new content loaded dynamically with javascript. My question is about if possible only load the content once with the html code generated by javascript or if there are any alternative to not do that.

Thanks!

Comment: plz provide the your js code

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear.

It looks like you want to **modify** an **existing** HTML node. 
Instead you are **adding** a new one, so you have them two times.